# Auth::guest() is not working

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using Auth::guest() for check the user is set or not. if is not redirect to the signin view.

Here is the code,
Home Controller :

```
public function index()
{
   if (Auth::guest())
    {
        return view ('signin');
    }
    else
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

it is not working properly

Comment: Share what you have included in this file ? do you have any middle ware included here ? which version you are using ?

Comment: i'm not using the middleware concept.my laravel version is 5.4

Comment: Are you able to get user detail if logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

when you say "not working"... are you always getting the signin view... any errors in the Laravel logs?

Comment: I expecting signin view when user not login into the system.

Comment: problem is resolved!! i am using make::view in another controller so i forgot to apply check the condition in there